# Android GPS Over Speed Alert

Tags: android, performance, gps

I have created an App which calculates the speed of Android device using `LocationListener` and `location.getSpeed()`. I set a Speed Limit using SMS `OSA 55`. Here OSA is `Over Speed Alert` and 55 is speed limit in `kmph`.
When the device travels more than `55 kmph` for more than 10 seconds it will send an sms to mobile number with Current Speed and Current Latitude and Longitude. I have done this using following code.

```
private void sendOverSpeedAlert() {
    Toast.makeText(MainPage.this,"Over Speed Alert Set",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final SharedPreferences account=getSharedPreferences("admins",MODE_PRIVATE);

    String overSpeed=account.getString("osa", "");
    double overSpeedKm=Double.parseDouble(overSpeed);
    final DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#");
    String overSpeedFormat=dFormat.format(overSpeedKm);
    final double overSpeedDouble=Double.parseDouble(overSpeedFormat);

    LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            double currentSpeed=(location.getSpeed())*3.6;
            String currentSpeedString=dFormat.format(currentSpeed);
            final double currentSpeedDouble=Double.parseDouble(currentSpeedString);
            if (currentSpeedDouble>overSpeedDouble){
                CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        double latitude=location.getLatitude();
                        double longitude=location.getLongitude();
                        DecimalFormat decimalFormat=new DecimalFormat("#.####");
                        Date date=new Date();
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
                        String time=sdf.format(date);

                        SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
                        String sms=" 'ALERT-OVER SPEED'\n\n'!+"+decimalFormat.format(latitude)+",+"+decimalFormat.format(longitude)+","+time+"'\n\nSpeed='"+currentSpeedDouble+"'Km/Hr('"+overSpeedDouble+"')";
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(logPreferences.getString("admin1",""),null,sms,null,null);

                        MediaPlayer media = new MediaPlayer();
                        media = MediaPlayer.create(MainPage.this, R.raw.buzzer);
                        media.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        media.setLooping(false);
                        media.start();
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    });

}
```

My problem is whenever the location changes by a decimal point it Listens speed and if it's higher than limit speed it sends SMS. It dried my SMS limits today by sending hundreds of sms. I don't want to send alert to each and every Latitude and Longitude changes. I just want to send single alert when the device goes over limit. And then the device has to reach `20 kmph` to Listen to next alert. Somebody help me. Thank you.

Comment: before you send a sms, test yout code by writing a log message instead. Once evrything works fine reennble sending of sms

Comment: @AlexWien I just set a Flag Variable and incremented it after message sent. Then it wouldn't go to the loop again and decremented the Flag once it reaches below 20.  I think this will help. I yet to test this.

Comment: this is a trial and error, type of programming, find first out what caused the high number of messages